# Replace strings in a certain column with awk

Tags: awk, gsub, backreference

I am trying to replace a string of numbers in the first column using awk, gsub and backreference.

For instance, my input file is

```
1-00001 1 1-00001
1-00001-01 1 1-00001
1-00001-02 1 1-00001
```

and my desired output is

```
1-00001-00 1 1-00001
1-00001-01 1 1-00001
1-00001-02 1 1-00001
```

I tried the following unix command

```
 awk '{gsub("^1-\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)$","^1-\1\2\3\4\5-00$",$1); print}' input
```

and the output was

```
^1-^A^B^C^D^E-00$ 1 1-00001
1-00001-01 1 1-00001
1-00001-02 1 1-00001
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my command?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `gensub`from `gnu awk` to get backreference.
But if you do tell us what you want, input and ouput, it can be done differently. Like this:

```
awk 'split($1,a,"-")!=3 {$1=$1 "-00"}1' file
1-00001-00 1 1-00001
1-00001-01 1 1-00001
1-00001-02 1 1-00001
```